# Local function arguments not visible in Chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone.js and when I call `save` on one of my models **in Chrome**, there is some very strange behavior. In the `Backbone.sync` function if I put a breakpoint on the first statement I see `arguments` is populated, but the three parameters are *not visible*... See the attached screenshot; how is this possible?

[image: Bogus parameter assignment]

The reason I ask is, I'm trying to figure out why a subsequent statement is failing and I can't see any of the values being used during the invocation

[image: More bogus values]

The debugger is again stating `options` and `method` are 'not available', but obviously they must have values otherwise the body of that `if` statement wouldn't be executing...

The error my browser raises when that bit of underlined code executes is

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://www.local-dev.com" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "http://secure-au.imrworldwide.com". Protocols, domains, and ports
>   must match.

The call to `model.toJSON(options)` appears to be running without error, so somehow the call to `JSON.stringify` is where the exception is raised?? I'm stumped!

I've also checked the value of `user.urlRoot` prior to invoking `user.save()` and its value is `/apps/entry/login/index`, which of course has nothing to do with secure-au.imrworldwide.com! Lastly, I checked and am running the latest version of Chrome, *Version 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit)*.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I've never used fiddle before, but I'll try to create one. Perhaps in that effort I'll determine the problem (one can only hope).

Comment: I just tried doing `.save()` on a simple model in chrome, and your screenshot does look strange indeed, I get all the expected values within `sync` execution.

Comment: By any chance, have you tested this with Chrome on a different workstation?

Comment: Yes, the QA department is experiencing the same issue.

Comment: WIthout being aware of your set up etc, my first thought would be that this is not actually an issue with the code, but - this might be a stretch -  it could be some kind of rouge spyware, a quick search for "imrworldwide"  seems to suggest the same. If you haven't already, you could try installing something like Ghostery to block imrworldwide.com from loading alltogether.